# height of iframe doesn't resize based on outer div height using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a general question about resizing iframe contents. 
I have observed that if I change the width of the outer div that contains the iframe, then the iframe contents adjust according to the outer div width specifications. The same doesn't hold true for the height attribute. Can someone explain me or guide more on this to me?

By changing the height and width attribute values, I meant specifying height and width in percentages and not in pixel values.

Example:

`<div style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="http://www.gizmodo.com"></iframe>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

if you want your iframe to respond to width changes and maintain the proportions, you have to play with the aspect ratio of the wrapper div with the padding like this:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qajXpi048nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So to specify the width and height of your iframe, you just need to play around with the padding-bottom of the wrapper div.

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggf2tLgo/).

[Original source](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php).

Comment: You have given fixed values of width and height as iframe attributes. May I know why is that?

Comment: I just copied the code from YouTube's share field as it is to show that it really doesn't matter. Those values are really not important, you can even delete them. The only value that determines the dimensions of your iframe in this configuration is the padding-bottom of you wrapper.

It works because the iframe is stretched to occupy the entirety of the parent.

Comment: That's the point of the question. I wanted to know if we can make the iframe scale according to the parent resize. The iframe does occupy the parent completely but if the parent's height changes, would the iframe contents get scaled accordingly to the parent then?